# What is the result of ''x '''∘ '''' in Frenet formulas in the differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry

α is an arbitrary curve I → R³

x is the cross product

∘ is the inner product

I want to have the result as simple expression as  .

Comment: You are not going to have something just in terms of $\kappa$. Show what you've tried computing and ask a specific question where you get stuck. I would recommend you start with an arclength parametrized curve.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I heared that equation is simplifyed by using frenet apparstus. The problem I had is that it doesn't looks like simplified at all when I try to deliverate directly α''' to get α'''' because all T,N,B are alive. And also it doesn't looks like having more simple expression when I try to use property of orthogonal by inner product. So, I don't know how to approach this problem.

Comment: Yes, it's going to have several terms, with derivatives of $\kappa$ and $\tau$ appearing. As I said, assume arclength parametrization so that you don't have to deal with speed and derivatives of speed. Just go for it.